# Java: passing the value of a String to another class to use for setText on Pane

Tags: java, string, swing, reference, call

I am quite new to this, I do not understand how classes communicate properly despite reading the docs, I think I need a working example to drill it in.

I have a Jlist and a JEditorPane sharing a JSplitPane. the list functionality is fine, however my Jeditorpane is in another class, I have obtained the string I need by:

```
public void setBookmarkPreview(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
bookmarkString = (String)this.getSelectedValue();
//System.out.println(bookmarkString);
```

this all works, however I have no idea how to pass this string to my "BookmarkPreview" class which extends JEditorPane, just so I can display the retrieved result above on the editor pane from the second class.

I've tried reading online but I can't get my head around the context.

**I created**

```
public static String bookmarkString;
```

Thinking it would be updated based on my list listener method, but the result in class 2 prints "null" so I am clearly missing something here.

Here is the second class where I tried to call the public static string

```
public class BookmarkPreview extends JEditorPane {

public BookmarkPreview() {

BookmarkPane test = new BookmarkPane();

this.setEditable(false);
setText(BookmarkPane.bookmarkString);
System.out.println(BookmarkPane.bookmarkString);
}   
}
```

Please, if you can provide an example using my wording it would be greatly appreciated, directing me to the docs won't help I assure you have have been trying for ages to wrap my head around it from scratch.

****UPDATE*****

ok I have created getters/setters:

```
public void bookmarkPreview(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
bookmarkString = (String)this.getSelectedValue();
setBookmarkString(bookmarkString);
 }


public String getBookmarkString() {
    return bookmarkString;
}

public void setBookmarkString(String bookmarkString) {
    this.bookmarkString = bookmarkString;
}
```

and updated the class that wants to recieve it:

```
public BookmarkPreview() {
BookmarkPane test = new BookmarkPane();
test.getBookmarkString();
this.setEditable(false);
setText(test.getBookmarkString());
System.out.println(test.getBookmarkString());
}   
}
```

Still nothing appears in the JEditorPane.

Comment: Maybe you could create a "getter": `public String getStr(){ return myString};`

Comment: Can you elaborate in context with my code? where does this go? which part of the string am I returning?

Comment: Typical class structure has getters and setters for the fields in the class. Rather than making bookmarkString static, have a getter and setter in BookmarkPane. When you want to access the value, you can call the getter and retrieve the value and then display it or whatever. If you want to change it, then you use the setter. The value of bookmarkString will be persisted in that instance of BookmarkPane.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me understand somewhat, but as I said, I have seen setter and getters docs/examples and I just cant seem to get them to work with my code. If someone could kindly write the example using my keywords/code so I can see it in action that would be great, ofcourse I understand that is doing it for me, but I'm at the breaking point.

Comment: @Test_Subject You have to know your code somewhat. Let's say that the String you want to have a getter/setter for is called `myString`. I already gave all the code necessary for a getter, and here is a setter: `public void setStr(String newString){ myString = newString;}`

Comment: note that you will have to call the getter from the instance of BookmarkPane that you created:
setText(test.getBookmarkString());
Furthermore, remove the static from the declaration of bookmarkString, as bookmarkString is better off as a field of BookmarkPane.
You don't really need a new setter, unless if you want to be able to overwrite bookmarkString bypassing the UI.

Comment: Speaking to your initial question, though, the reason why you are getting "null" at your print string, is because bookmarkString has no value at that point. If we follow the callflow, your BookmarkPane test gets created and then we access BookmarkPane. However, creating an instance of BookmarkPane here isn't really doing anything to bookmarkString, set BookmarkPreview is never getting called. Even so, since bookmarkString is static, it does exist in memory, so no error is thrown when you try to print it out.

Comment: I think I have done the things you have mentioned, I have updated my original question with the current code, but still nothing appears in the editor pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on which way you want the communication to work.

To my mind, the editor doesn't care about the book mark list, but the list will want to know about the editor (so it can set the book mark).

What I would do is maintain a reference to the editor within the list component (passed in either via the constructor or a setter of some kind) which would allow the list, when it's changed to call a method of the editor that would update the bookmark position (such as `setBookMark`).

Equally, I would allow the list to request a book mark from the editor at it's current position, maybe something like `newBookMark` or such

Comment: Both classes are extention class of their respective U.I E.G (BookmarkPane is extends Jlist) , BookmarkPreview extends JEditorPane, both are initilized from my main class) so I'm not sure how to go about your method. any input towards the method we have in progress would great?

Comment: So, your `BookmarkPane` needs to given a reference to `BookmarkPane` either directly via the constructor or indirectly via some kind of `setter`.  You need to need to provide functionality that the `BookmarkPane` can use to change the book mark on the `BookmarkPane`

Comment: Thank You! Your post + Eclipse code generator helped me understand how to pass reference properly between classes. Ironically I had already done it twice before without realising. Also thank you to the others who helped I think it pushed me to understand setters/getters aswell, but for other methods.